# fsolve mismatch shape error when nonlinear equations solver called from ODE solver

Tags: python, scipy, shapes, mismatch, odeint

I have a system of two nonlinear equations inside my function "par_impl(y)", which I can solve using scipy.optimize.root standalone. Here "y" is a parameter.
But I would like this system to be called from the ODE solver odeint in order to solve it for different value of "y", coupled to a simple ODE.
This gives me fsolve mismatch shape error.

> import numpy as np
>
> from scipy.optimize import root import
>
> matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>
> from scipy.integrate import odeint
>
> def par_impl(y):
>
> ```
> def functionh(x):
>     return [y + (x[0]**2) - x[1] -23, -4 - y*x[0] + (x[1]**2)]
> sol = root(functionh, [1, 1])
>
> return sol.x
> ```
>
> def dy_dt(y, t):
>
> ```
> dydt = (y**0.5) + par_impl(y)[0]
>
> return dydt
> ```
>
> ls = np.linspace(0, 2, 50)    y_0 = 2
>
> Ps = odeint(dy_dt, y_0, ls)
>
> y = Ps[:,0]
>
> plt.plot(ls, y, "+", label="X") plt.legend(); plt.figure()

The error that I obtain is:

> File
>   "C:\Users\matteo\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py",
>   line 41, in _check_func
>       raise TypeError(msg)
>
> TypeError: fsolve: there is a mismatch between the input and output
>   shape of the 'func' argument 'functionh'.Shape should be (2,) but it
>   is (2, 1).

Comment: Format your  code properly and include imports so that people can copy paste and reproduce error without googling for missing imports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `y` was a list of `len` = `1` in your code. To access its element, you needed `y[0]` in your function. Below is a working version of your code (not showing the whole code) with the output plot.

```
from scipy.optimize import root
from scipy.integrate import odeint
# Other plotting and numpy imports

def par_impl(y):
    def functionh(x):
        return [y[0] + (x[0]**2) - x[1] -23, -4 - y[0]*x[0] + (x[1]**2)] # y --> y[0]
    sol = root(functionh, ([1, 1]))
    return sol.x

# dy_dt function here  

# Rest of your code unchanged

plt.plot(ls, y, "+", label="X") 
plt.legend()
```

**Output**

[image]